# Can not install Groovy plugin in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, plugins, groovy

when I install Groovy 2.0 plugin in Jenkins version 2.46.2, the installation is ok, no error, but I did not see "Groovy Installation" in configure system like the instruction link https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin, i aslo re-installed this plugin and restart jenkins service, but no luck. Is there something I miss? Pls advise me how to fix this issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tool configurations have been moved over to "Global Tool Configuration" page under "Manage Jenkins" link in recent Jenkins versions (Sorry, I don't know the exact version when this change happened). "Groovy Installations"  should be present under this page.

Comment: Thanks you, I got it.